# Is there any answer in NSIS?

Tags: checkbox, callback, nsis

Could you tell me how to do like "MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX" on Welcome page?

And I do control event when I clicked checkbox.

Comment: Why the down vote? Anyway, should this checkbox skip the license page or do something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the MUI documentation:

> **Page Custom Functions**
>
> ... the show function is called, which can be used to customize the interface.

You can add extra controls in this callback. For MUIv2, that means nsDialogs:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW WelcomeShow
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE WelcomeLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE LicensePre
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Var SkipLicensePage

Function WelcomeShow
${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 120u 150u 90% 12u "Accept license"
Pop $0
SetCtlColors $0 ${MUI_TEXTCOLOR} ${MUI_BGCOLOR}
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(p$0,p0,i0,i0,i0,i0,i0x33|0x40)' ; Force on top of the existing label
${NSD_SetState} $0 $SkipLicensePage
${NSD_OnClick} $0 WelcomeCheckClicked
FunctionEnd

Function WelcomeLeave
${NSD_GetState} $0 $SkipLicensePage
FunctionEnd

Function WelcomeCheckClicked
Pop $1 ; Throw away
MessageBox mb_ok "You clicked me!"
FunctionEnd

Function LicensePre
${IfThen} $SkipLicensePage <> 0 ${|} Abort ${|}
FunctionEnd
```